# Adding Cumulative Values in loops in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, tabular

I've been trying to get the data in the "Interest Paid" column in this program to add together with each interaction of the while loop but it just shows the next value of intrp. Here's the program:

```
function displayWelcome() {
    var welcome = "This program will determine the time to pay off a credit card and interest paid based on the current balance, the interest rate, and the monthly payments made.";
    return welcome;
}

function calculateMinimumPayment(bal, intr) {
    var min = bal * intr;
    return min;
}

function displayPayments(bal, intr, min) {
    var top1 = "Balance on your credit card: " + bal + "\nInterest Rate: " + intr + "\nAssuming the minimum payment of 2% of the balance ($20 min)\nYour minimum payment would be $" + min;
    var top2 = "PAYOFF SCHEDULE\n______________\nYear\tBalance\t\tPayment Num\tInterest Paid\n";
    console.log(top1);
    console.log(top2);
    var yearcount = 0;
    var year = 0;
    var paynum = 0;
    while (bal + (intr - min) >= 0) {
        paynum++;
        bal = bal + (intr - min);
        intrp = bal * (intr / 12);
        var tbl1 = parseFloat(bal).toFixed(2) + "\t\t" + paynum + "\t\t" + parseFloat(intrp).toFixed(2);
        if (yearcount % 12 === 0) {
            year = year + 1;
            var tbl2 = " " + year + "      " + tbl1;
        } else {
            var tbl2 = "\t" + tbl1;
        }
        yearcount++;
        console.log(tbl2);
    }
}
console.log(displayWelcome());
console.log(displayPayments(1500, 0.18, calculateMinimumPayment(1500, 0.02)));
```

Here's the output:

```
This program will determine the time to pay off a credit card and interest paid
based on the current balance, the interest rate, and the monthly payments made.
Balance on your credit card: 1500
Interest Rate: 0.18
Assuming the minimum payment of 2% of the balance ($20 min)
Your minimum payment would be $30
PAYOFF SCHEDULE
______________
Year    Balance         Payment Num     Interest Paid

 1      1470.18         1               22.05
        1440.36         2               21.61
        1410.54         3               21.16
        1380.72         4               20.71
        1350.90         5               20.26
        1321.08         6               19.82
        1291.26         7               19.37
        1261.44         8               18.92
        1231.62         9               18.47
        1201.80         10              18.03
        1171.98         11              17.58
        1142.16         12              17.13
 2      1112.34         13              16.69
        1082.52         14              16.24
        1052.70         15              15.79
        1022.88         16              15.34
        993.06          17              14.90
        963.24          18              14.45
        933.42          19              14.00
        903.60          20              13.55
        873.78          21              13.11
        843.96          22              12.66
        814.14          23              12.21
        784.32          24              11.76
 3      754.50          25              11.32
        724.68          26              10.87
        694.86          27              10.42
        665.04          28              9.98
        635.22          29              9.53
        605.40          30              9.08
        575.58          31              8.63
        545.76          32              8.19
        515.94          33              7.74
        486.12          34              7.29
        456.30          35              6.84
        426.48          36              6.40
 4      396.66          37              5.95
        366.84          38              5.50
        337.02          39              5.06
        307.20          40              4.61
        277.38          41              4.16
        247.56          42              3.71
        217.74          43              3.27
        187.92          44              2.82
        158.10          45              2.37
        128.28          46              1.92
        98.46           47              1.48
        68.64           48              1.03
 5      38.82           49              0.58
        9.00            50              0.14
```

As you can see, the "Interest Paid" column doesn't add together, it just shows the current value of intrp.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been trying to get the data in the "Interest Paid" column in this
>   program to add together with each interaction of the while loop but it
>   just shows the next value of intrp

that is because you are assigning the value to `intrp` rather than accumulating the previous values.

replace

```
intrp = bal * (intr / 12);
```

with

```
intrp += bal * (intr / 12);
```

Comment: Now it starts off high and ends low. I need it to  start at 22.05 and add each number under it onto it.

Comment: @dungo can you share a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

if you add accumulative interest

https://jsfiddle.net/om1a90qc/

```
function displayPayments(bal, intr, min) {
    var acum = 0;
    var top1 = "Balance on your credit card: " + bal + "\nInterest Rate: " + intr + "\nAssuming the minimum payment of 2% of the balance ($20 min)\nYour minimum payment would be $" + min;
    var top2 = "PAYOFF SCHEDULE\n______________\nYear\tBalance\t\tPayment Num\tInterest Paid\t\tInterest Paid\n";
    console.log(top1);
    console.log(top2);
    var yearcount = 0;
    var year = 0;
    var paynum = 0;
    while (bal + (intr - min) >= 0) {
        paynum++;
        bal = bal + (intr - min);
        intrp = bal * (intr / 12);
        acum = (parseFloat(acum) + parseFloat(intrp)).toFixed(2);
        var tbl1 = parseFloat(bal).toFixed(2) + "\t\t" + paynum + "\t\t" + parseFloat(intrp).toFixed(2) + "\t\t" + acum;
        if (yearcount % 12 === 0) {
            year = year + 1;
            var tbl2 = " " + year + "      " + tbl1;
        } else {
            var tbl2 = "\t" + tbl1;
        }
        yearcount++;
        console.log(tbl2);
    }
}
console.log(displayWelcome());
console.log(displayPayments(1500, 0.18, calculateMinimumPayment(1500, 0.02)));
```

Comment: Now it starts off high and ends low. I need it to start at 22.05 and add each number under it onto it.

Comment: I don't understand your problems.